# Monodevelop .Net cross platform custom drawing application

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm looking for good suggestions on where to start with an educational application I am designing.

I want my application to be compatible with Windows and OSX - my research seems to suggest that about 40% of the audience would be using a mac.

I'm keen to stick to .net/c sharp and the Mono framework.

The application is reasonably simple - it would be graphical, containing a tool bar with a menu and a few buttons. The main area on screen will contain custom graphics - I would draw onto an area in the main window using some algorithms I'm developing.

I would also need to play music, preferably mp3.

The drawing area would be animated, but not heavy duty - i.e. fairly simple line drawings, not 3d or shaded, etc.

I'm thinking about creating a GTK sharp 2.0 application in Monodevelop, using a DrawingArea for my custom drawing.

I'm not overly concerned with making the application look "Native", this would be a bonus but not essential.

I can elaborate on details if needs be, but does this sound like a reasonable starting block?

Any recommendations on a decent cross platform drawing library I could use?

Comment: The [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace is quite capable, so you should be OK if you stick with it. I think your will find sound to be much more of an issue.

Comment: Good luck with your project! It's always a pleasure to see people like you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at Mono Cairo: http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo

Comment: They are also now closed source. [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/) may be more suitable, as it is based on Mono.

Comment: I just noticed when I wanted to link to it. Looks like a future commercial project...

Comment: Why not put pinta as an answer ?

Comment: Note that GTK itself uses Cairo for drawing.

Comment: I've spent some time doing some research into Cairo and found that it works beautifully. Also, it's easy to use which is a bonus. Thanks for the prompt responses.

Comment: Also, while GTK itself does use Cairo, GTK projects in mono do not have Cairo drawing capabilities out of the box. I had to hunt around on my system for the Cairo assembly to add as a reference to my project.