# Drawing tools of Gtk# MonoDevelop

Tags: drawing, cross-platform, monodevelop, gtk#

I want to use Gtk# and MonoDevelop for drawing some graphic primitives (for example, line's, rectangle's, etc.). In the .NET Framework I used next code

```
Graphics graphics=pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 0,0,100,100);
```

But how can I do it by the means of Gtk#? I found class DrawingArea, but how can I draw in that class? Could you help me please?

Comment: I'm actually looking for the same thing and didn't have much of a success with Cairo. Have you managed to accomplish what you were trying to do?

Comment: Yes. I'm using System.Drawing.Graphics for drawing and then I convert Bitmap to Pixbuf. My code is:       protected Gdk.Pixbuf ImageToPixbuf(System.Drawing.Image Image)
       {
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            stream.Position = 0;
            Gdk.Pixbuf pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(stream);
            return pixbuf;
        }
       } I'm so sory, but I have not time

Comment: I actually managed to get my stuff going on with a DrawingArea and GDK/GTK. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Expose handler, create a Cairo context and draw with that.

For a tutorial, see http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/gtksharptutorial/drawing/

Comment: Link is down. This other question could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531607/drawing-with-cairo-in-monodevelop-on-windows